# SQLite exception in java : attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, netbeans

I have created a java application having sqlite db(using netbeans). I have also created a .exe file, and the database is there in the folder containing the executable file. But when i run the .exe file, read operation is working fine. When i try updating or writing on to the db, am running into the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException:[SQLITE_READONLY] Attempt to write a readonly database.
```

I tried searching for solutions, but I found solutions like changing the permissions.
I did change the permissions of the db as well as the containing folder in windows. The error persists.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have multiple processes are working on the database?

Comment: Maybe try running the .exe as an admin. Hmm, could be locked by another instance? Could be some sort of (perpetual?) read operation occurring that could also lock it. Maybe try launching the app and performing a write before any read.

Comment: @HaifengZhang nope i dont have multiple processes accessing the db.

Comment: @VivekChavda i have a login system so i need to perform the read first then the write operation. Adding to it when i run the code from the ide it works fine.

Comment: Can you insert here the source code of the .exe file?

Comment: it works fine if i shift the folder to some other drive from C drive.